# Can one choose a precise biometric authentication using BiometricPrompt?

Tags: android, api, fingerprint, android-biometric-prompt

I am looking for implementing Fingerprint authentication on an Android app, using BiometricPrompt, but I don't seem to be able to choose only Fingerprint. I don't want my users to be able to authenticate with Iris or Face, I just want to allow Fingerprint. Do you know if it is possible?

Thank you!

Comment: Not possible to choose

Answer (score 0):

As I've explained elsewhere: some devices only have one form factor, some have many form factors. Which form factor your app ends up using isn't really up to you; it's up to the OEM implementation. As explained in [this blog post](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/migrating-from-fingerprintmanager-to-biometricprompt-4bc5f570dccd), whether a form factor is **Strong** or **Weak** doesn't depend on your code -- the OEM decides. **However**, you can request that a device uses **Strong** authentication for your app by specifying a `CryptoObject` when you call `authenticate()`.

It so happen that presently most devices with multiple form factors implement Fingerprint as their **Strong** biometrics. Hence, specifying a `CryptoObject` when you call `authenticate()` will likely give you what you want.